# Errors Loading External File into Web2Py Controller Method

Tags: python, web-services, opencv, web-deployment, web2py

I am trying to build a web2Py api that also uses OPENCV (Computer Vision Library). I have tested the OPENCV loading method in a folder on a local machine (code works). When creating a method in the default controller for my web2Py application, the code runs, but the cascade will not load, although the .xml file is located in the same folder as the default.py under the application controller. I checked permissions and enabled all permissions on the .xml file (doesn't seem to be the issue). Do I need to place the file in a different location?

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

no_classifier = face_cascade.empty()

The cascade always returns true for empty (it did not load).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the working directory at the time you try to load the cascade? What if you use an absolute path?

Comment: Dan: Thanks for the reply. I am running this on an online service, so it is difficult to tell the current working directory. I will do some checks to see if I can answer. Putting the files in the private folder and constructing the full path like in Anthony's answer worked. I tried a few relative paths but was unsure of the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python working directory will not be the folder containing the controller. In general, it is best to simply construct the full path the to the file. It is also recommended to put such files in the application's /private folder:

```
    import os
    filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'private',
                            'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(filepath)
```

Comment: Anthony, this is exactly right. Thanks for the help. Do you know a good resource I can view where I can learn more about this? Thanks again!